# How do I redirect a checkbox to another page in my app if checked Xamarin Android C#?

Tags: c#, android, checkbox, xamarin

I am making an android app using C# in Xamarin studio. I managed to make the checkboxes and among other things. I need to know what code I would need to use make a the checkbox go to redirect to another page if checked. I am new to programming so I am sure this is an easy question but I am having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do

```
private void MainPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
}
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        // your code to go to the other page.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code though. that is what I am looking for. What would I need to put in to redirect it?